# Nginx proxy by alphabet

Tags: nginx, vps, redirect, subdomain

I have three VPS servers, each one has its own ip address.
The Server One is supposed to be a proxy server, which will be listen for `domain.com` and `*.domain.com`.

Is it possible to configure that first VPS so that if a client asks for any subdomain which starts with letter from A to O (for example `demo.domain.com` or `buddy.domain.com`) they get sent to Server Two, and if the subdomain begins with P to Z they get sent to Server Three?

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, everything's possible:

I presume you don't actually mean `redirect` when you say "redirect":

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     example.com *.example.com;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
    if ($host ~ "^[a-o]") {
        proxy_pass http://2.example.net:80;
    }
    if ($host ~ "^[p-z]") {
        proxy_pass http://3.example.net:80;
    }
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! i'll try it! :) One more question: What kind of regex i should use if second VPS would hosts subdomains with letters from A to O and with nummbers from 0 to 9, for example "777casino.domain.com" - Something like `"^[a-o]|^[0-9]"`?

Comment: An expression for "letters and numbers" would be `[A-Za-z0-9]` (so `[A-Za-z0-9]+\.domain\.com` would work if you always want it to be `subdomain.domain.com`) - you can change the character range for the first character (`[A-Oa-o0-9].[A-Za-z0-9]+` for example) to do what you talk about in the question. The nginx folks' [rewrite documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) suggests using [Regex Pal](http://regexpal.com) to test your regular expressions.

Comment: @Eugene, you would use `"^[0-9a-o]"`